# How to add boolean column based on expression?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table `T1`:

| Id | R1 | R2 | R3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | r1_d1 | r2_d1 | r3_d1 |
| Id2 | r1_d2 | r2_d2 | r3_d2 |
| Id3 | r1_d3 | r2_d2 | r3_d3 |
| Id4 | r1_d4 | r2_d4 | r3_d4 |

Table `T2`:

| Id | K_R1 | K2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | r1_d1 | k2_d1 |
| Id2 | r1_d3 | k2_d2 |
| Id3 | r1_d4 | k2_d4 |

I need some properties of first table and an additional result indicating if `T1.R1 == T2.K_R1`:

| Id | R1 | R2 | P1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id1 | r1_d1 | r2_d1 | true |
| Id2 | r1_d2 | r2_d2 | false |
| Id3 | r1_d3 | r2_d2 | true |
| Id4 | r1_d4 | r2_d4 | true |

`LEFT JOIN` will return all entries of `T1` and matching entries of `T2`, but will have all properties of `T2` too, which is not needed. How (considering performance too) to exclude unnecessary properties and produce a boolean- instead of actual value?

Comment: there must be an error  the first table has Id2  r1_d4  and the second  Id3  r1_d4 so the result set can not be achieved

Comment: The data samples are complete junk. Data samples are required to help other understand what your problem is and what you are trying to achieve. It is not easy to think of a more useless data sample.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `EXISTS` operator as the following:

```
SELECT Id, R1, R2,
       EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 T2 WHERE T2.K_R1 = T1.R1) AS P1
FROM table1 T1
ORDER BY Id, R1
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ou9aoYRE).

Answer (score 0):

The join itself doesn't "return" anything, so I wouldn't worry about the number of columns that *could* be returned. You can put exactly what you want in your `SELECT` clause.

You can use a `CASE` statement to return true or false.

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT 
 t1.id, 
 t1.r1, 
 t1.r2, 
 CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END p1
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
 ON t1.r1 = t2.k_r1
```

Or

```
SELECT 
 t1.*, 
 CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END p1
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
  ON t1.r1 = t2.k_r1
```

Those options assume that there is at most one matching record in t2. If that isn't the case, you would probably want to either use `GROUP BY` (with the `JOIN`) or use an `EXISTS` in your `SELECT` (without the `JOIN`). The `MAX` in this is example should work since "true" is alphabetically greater than "false", and if there is at least one "true" you want to return "true."

```
SELECT 
 t1.id, 
 t1.r1, 
 t1.r2, 
 MAX(CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END) p1
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
 ON t1.r1 = t2.k_r1
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.r1, t1.r2
```